# Can I run a Grails 2.2.5 application with Java 8?

Tags: grails

I have been trying to run a Grails 2.2.5 application, which works fine on Tomcat 6 and Java 7, on a Tomcat 8 installation with Java 8 (specifically '1.8.0_181'), and have been having startup errors. I seem to recall some compatibility issues but I can't find anything about Grails 2.2.x with Java 8. The error message in question is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Groovy is the limitation here. The first version of Groovy that worked with Java 8 was version 2.3, and Grails 2.4 was the first version to use Groovy 2.3+. Since you cannot change the version of Groovy that Grails uses, you'll need to stick with Java 7 (not great) or upgrade (much better).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Long term, an upgrade is the plan, but for now I'll downgrade to Java 7.

Comment: In addition, Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.